# Extra de-limiter caused data to shift to the right 1 column

Tags: excel, vba

So I was given a .csv file, and unfortunately one of the field's sometimes contains a customer name in the format lastname, firstname which is throwing off the data. Fortunately, I can detect when this happens because one of the columns that is getting shifted has a fixed value. An example:

Good row:

```
[New Contact!]  [phonenumber]   5939262 [Unknown]   2000    5083    5083
```

Bad row:

```
[lastname]  [firstname] [phonenumber]   2800    [Unknown]   2000    5061    5061
```

So if the 5th column = [Unknown], I know that the the columns need to be shifted left for that row. The first column contains data that is not being used, so if I lose the name I don't care, it's just the numbers.

Is there any easy way to do this without regenerating the data?

Comment: Are you parsing the CSV file yourself (using VBA) or using Excel? If you're doing it yourself, before you split the row into columns, count the number of commas in the text. If it's 6, then do nothing, if it's seven - replace the first with a semi-colon for instance. Then parse the line as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this macro to fix the file after the import:

```
Sub fixIt()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows ' <-- put the right sheet name here
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r) > 7 Then r.value = r.Offset(, 1).value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That is so disturbingly simple it hurts.

Comment: Very simple, did the trick, only took a few minutes (close to 1 million rows), thank you.

Comment: @MartinBoros you are welcome. It would be probably an interesting question how to accelerate the code. For instance try to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to see if it imporves the speed.